# How to manage multiple css files in rails 4?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass

I have the css file for everything under a controller included in `app/views/layouts/mycontroller.html.erb`:

```
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "mysubdirectory/main" %>
</head>
```

But I've decomposed my css into some that are for particular views, like home.css.scss (may not be the best way to  break it down?).  Before, I was additionally included extra css.  E.g. in `app/views/mycontroller/home.html.erb`, I would lead with another `styleshet_link_tag`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "mysubdirectory/home" %>
```

I am including `gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'` in my Gemfile and the precompiling happens on heroku.

None of the CSS seems to be loading or only some of it and not the sum of the two sets of CSS rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Rails to precompile your additional files, in your application.rb add

```
config.assets.precompile += ['mysubdirectory/main']
```

Rails will only precompile application.css and application.js by default.

Comment: In config/environments/production.rb, I've now changed the boolean to true for:
config.serve_static_assets = true 

and added a regex I found online to include ALL css and js files
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )

I lost my workflow now though.  It's much more difficult to prototype without deploying to heroku.