# Ruby on Rails CSS not refreshing/reloading every page change

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have pages in my rails application such as a landing page which I excluded from the normal theme of the site. Therefore it does not use `application.scss`. If I go from any of my normal pages to the landing page it keeps the same background color and does not load most of the CSS from the landing page. This actually happens in multiple cases.

Is there any way I can load CSS freshly every time a new page is loaded?

Comment: That could be related with the browser´s cache. You can test it, deleting it and loading the page again. If the problem is solved, you can define by appcache and htaccess files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining another layout file for landing page or many more pages in case you want in future & include css file separately in this new layout file

Answer (score 0):

> You need to tell Rails to precompile your additional files, in your
>   application.rb add

```
config.assets.precompile += ['mysubdirectory/main']
```

> Rails will onlyprecompile application.css and application.js by
>   default.

[How to manage multiple css files in rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988309/how-to-manage-multiple-css-files-in-rails-4)

Comment: I already did that. For some reason if I just refresh it goes back to normal and renders the CSS of the landing page. Any idea how to force render it

Comment: May I ask why you've splitted the CSS?

Comment: I didn't want elements like my navbar and footer to be rendered in the landing page so I made sure it didn't compile the application html or CSS

Comment: Ok, then I would recommend you re-thinking the structure of your HTML - Such as creating a separate view-files for Header and Footer, and then rendering those file(s) only on the pages where you want to show header and footer.